# Build Optimization for c# Solution

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, optimization, dll, msbuild

I am working on project and the solution has 40+ projects.
I have two build configuration Lite and Release. 
Lite builds A-G projects and Release builds A- M Projects. 
Is is possible to make a release target that builds Lite and uses the dlls from lite for Release?

Comment: You can output your artefacts to a specific folder (you need to do this in each project) and reference the DLLs directly instead of using project references.

Comment: How would release configuration knows that it does not have to build A-G and it has to build only H- M projects ?

Comment: It wouldn't. It would depend on where you output the debug/release artefacts and how you reference them.

Comment: Is there way to check if I build this Projects skip those project?

Comment: In Visual Studio Solution "Configuration Manager", you have the option to determine which all projects to build during build of a configuration. So for your lite configuration, you can select projects A-G to build and in case of release configuration you can make projects H-M build.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is.

1. Have everything reference its dependencies from a relative folder.

   .\MySolution01.sln

   .\MyCSProj01\MyCSProj01.csproj

   .\MyCSProj02\MyCSProj02.csproj

   .\MyCSProjN\MyCSProjN.csproj

   .\ThirdPartyReferences\

   .\ThirdPartyReferences\MyCoolDll.dll

   .\ThirdPartyReferences\SomePDFLibrary.dll

and in the csproj

```
 <Reference Include="SomePDFLibrary">
     <HintPath>..\ThirdPartyReferences\SomePDFLibrary.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

2.

Write msbuild tasks that

A. Pull down code for "Lite".
B.  Build "Lite".
C.  Pull down code for "Release".
D.  Copy files from "Lite" over to the ThirdPartyReferences folder(s) for "Release".
E.  Build "Release".

Alternate idea.

When "Lite" builds, "publish" those dll's to a binary repository.
"Ivy" (apache) is the non-microsoft one. (You could use the command line version of ivy.  But most Microsoft developers won't go here)
Nuget (with a local repository) is the "microsoft flavor" of a ~binary repository.

http://gregorsuttie.com/2011/01/03/using-a-nuget-local-repository/

Then when "Release" builds, it "pulls down" its binaries from the binary-repository.